# When does $x^{n}=y^{n}$ imply $x=y$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $m$. Let $n$ be relatively prime to $m$. Let $x,y\in G$ such that $x^{n}=y^{n}$ prove that $x=y$.

I was able to prove this result if $G$ is abelian using the map $x\mapsto x^{n}$ and showing the kernal is $1$. But if $G$ is not abelian this is not a homomorphism and a different technique must be taken. I don't really know what to do when $G$ is not abelian. Any ideas would be great thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: let $k$ be a multiplicative inverse for $n$ modulo $m$, i.e., $k \cdot n \equiv 1 \mod m$.

Comment: Really? Not sure why that would be the case...

Comment: Yeah it told me I had to wait 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If $(m,n)=1$, there there exist positive integer $k,\ell$, such that $km-\ell n=1$ or $\ell n-km=1.$ Take the first case, then:
$$
x^n=y^n \Rightarrow x^{\ell n}=y^{\ell n} \Rightarrow x^{km+1}=y^{km+1}.
$$ 
But $x^m=y^m=e$, where $e$ is the identity, as the order of each element divides the order of the group. Thus
$$
x=x^{km}x=x^{km+1}=y^{km+1}=y^{km}y=y.
$$ 
In the case $\ell n-km=1$, following the same procedure we obtain that $x^{-1}=y^{-1}$, and thus $e=xx^{-1}=xy^{-1}$, which implies that $x=y$ as well.

Comment: You're a professor. Why don't you stop providing so many complete solutions and let the OP work with the hints people give them for a while?